# Python: Read values into empty array and then back into file

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, file-io

I would like to read numbers from a txt file (highscore.txt) in python and assign those values to an empty array (highscores).

Then I'd like to add another value into the array and then overwrite the file with the new values in the array.

I've put together a program but it doesn't give me the desired output.  Please see what's wrong with it...

Read from file:

```
highscores = []
#Read values from file and put them into array
file = open('highscore.txt', 'r') #read from file
file.readline() #read heading line
for line in file:
    highscores.append(file.readline())
file.close() #close file
```

Add value and overwrite file:

```
highscores.append(wins)
# Print sorted highscores print to file
file = open('highscore.txt', 'w') #write to file
file.write('Highscores (number of wins out of 10 games):\n') #write heading line
for line in highscores:
    file.write(str(line))
file.close() #close file
```

It needs work in such a way that I can (once this is working) sort the array with the added value before overwriting the file again...

I expect to read from a file:

```
Highscores (number of wins out of 10 games):
8
6
5
5
3
1
0
0
```

Read those value into the array
Then to add (let's say) 4 to the array
Then overwrite the file with the new values

In this case we can expect the output to be:

```
Highscores (number of wins out of 10):
8
6
5
5
3
1
0
0
4
```

Hope you can find out what's wrong there...

Edit:  Thanks to EvenListe's answer I could find a solution, here's the relevant code that I've used to get my program working perfectly (includes the array that gets added being sorted in descending order after being added)

```
from __future__ import print_function

highscores = []
with open("highscore.txt", "r") as f:
    f.readline() # Reads header
    for line in f:
        highscores.append(line.strip())

highscores.append(wins)
highscores = sorted(highscores, key=int, reverse=True)
# Print sorted highscores print to file
with open("highscore.txt", "w") as f:
  for val in highscores:
    print(val, file=f)
```

If you want to test out what the lines in the file are you can use this (I used it for before adding the array and after adding the array, it really helps finding out what's wrong without you having to constantly open the file):

```
print('Highscores (number of wins out of 10 games):')
for lines in highscores:
    print(lines)
```

Comment: this is very similar to a previous question... Please state in details what you expect and what you see (especially content of highscore.txt)

Comment: Updated my question, it always works for the first input (if there are no values), but if I run it again with a value in (or in the case above with many values) it doesn't give me the desired result...

Comment: You might wish to also add information on what actually happens.

Comment: Ok, so I've changed it based off your Answer Christoph, now if I use 4 as the value for wins the file will will have only 4's written to it (in all the places of the other numbers)

Comment: Ok found the issue!!  One of my variables (that I used for checking the file) was misnamed and ended up just using the input value instead of each of the values of the array.  Man I feel stupid now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the expected result vs actual result, but my guess is you need to strip the `\n` from the lines your read:

```
from __future__ import print_function
highscores = []
with open("highscore.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    highscores.append(line.strip())

highscores.append(wins)
with open("highscore.txt", "w") as f:
  for val in highscores:
    print(val, file=f)
```

Comment: Turns out this is what's giving me grief, Problem is now, I get a whole load of crazy text when I use strip() instead of what I desire...

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, one obvious issue with your code is your

```
for line in infile:
    highscores.append(infile.readline())
```

which skips every other line. You should have

```
for line in infile:
    highscores.append(line)
```

or easier:

```
highscores=infile.readlines()
highscores=highscores[1:]  #Remove header
```

Comment: Ok so now if the number (wins) I append to the array is 4, all the values printed to the file are 4 (9 values)

Comment: @Barry, you may consider adding an _edit_ stanza to your OP, with the new code.